# Kotlin - Validating URL with custom URL scheme

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app, I can have web URL starting with "https://" or "http://" or URL with custom scheme starting with "custom://" or "testing://".

I tried using `URLUtil.isValidUrl()`, but this returns true only if URL starts with http or https.

How can I validate the URL with custom scheme in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand right, you just need to validate if the syntaxe is right, right ?

I did an sample here to validate URLs using Regex

```
val regex = "([A-Za-z]*:\\/\\/)?\\S*".toRegex()

fun isValidUrl(url: String): Boolean {
    return regex.containsMatchIn(url)
}
```

Comment: isValidURL checks for all the other URL's mentioned. I looked at the implementation of isValidURL.

Comment: friendly tip: link-only answers are downvoted and not seen as answers. consider quoting the relevant parts from the links or adding this as a comment instead

Comment: @Gorio - Will try this out.

Comment: @Gorio - Unfortunately this returns true for invalid URL's too. For example if my URL is "test:^/something?a={123}&b={xyz}". This comes out to be a valid URL.

Comment: Sure. Just adjust the regex to accept only yours URLs